# How to update child entity of another entity in CoreData

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, attributes, entity

I am using CoreData in my application to "cache" data coming back from my server. One of the entities (parent) I have has a one to many relationship with another entity (child). So if you were to look at the parent entity in the data modeler in xcode you would see it has several attributes one being an id that I can use to access the correct parent entity and then a one to many relation ship with the child entity.

The child element has about 20 attributes, One or two of which I would like to update and save in CoreData when the user performs some actions in the app.

My question is: I would like to know how or where to start to achieve an update in a child element in my CoreData.

A good example of my structure would be this example below. My Parent Entity has these attributes

> - iD
> - fName
> - lName
> - kids

My child entity has these attributes

```
 - iD
 - fName
 - lName
 - age
 - hobbies
```

I would like to be able to update age and hobbies attributes in the respective entity.

(Sorry if I have used the wrong words (parent/child) to describe the relationship, I wasn't sure what to use).

Comment: What exactly is your problem? Do you want to update all Child objects or one specific object? Why can't you just set the properties of an object? More information is needed ...

Comment: Well I am not sure how to update something in coredata I know how to read and write whole entities but im not sure how to update a single value or row inside a child entity.

Comment: You cannot update a single attribute. You have to fetch the object, set the new attributes and save the context (which saves *all* changes).

Comment: okay, that seems very redundant but thats okay. So now my question is once i have updated the object I have fectched how do i save the context?

Comment: `[managedObjectContext save:&error];`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is as simple as changing the properties and saving.

```
child.age = 14;
child.hobbies = setOfHobbies;
[self.managedObjectContext save:nil];
```